# Print tree recursively

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, tree

I wish to print (to List> each path of tree-leaf with c# (preferably recursively)

In case of tree:

```
               A
         B           C
      D  E  F       G  H
    I
```

Outcome I wish to get is list of list of leaves (A is leaf, ABDI is list of leaves):

```
ABDI
ABE
ABF
ACG
ACH
```

I was trying different loops like foreach but I have no idea when to print to get whole path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [depth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first).

Solution is:

```
public class Node {
    public List<Node> Children {get;set;}
    public string Label {get;set;}
}

public static void Print(Node node, string result)
{                        
    if (node.Children == null || node.Children.Count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        return;
    }
    foreach(var child in node.Children)
    {
        Print(child, result + child.Label);
    }
}
```

call it like this:

```
Print(root, root.Label);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this: (calling the first time ListNodes(node, "");

```
private void ListNodes(TreeNode node, string root)
{
    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
        {
            ListNodes(n, root + node.Text);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(" " + root + node.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Console.WriteLine to get the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a structure like this:

```
class Node {
    List<Node> Children {get;set;}
    string Label {get;set;}
}
```

you can print the paths with a recursive method like:

```
void PrintPaths (Node node, List<Node> currentPath)
{
    currentPath = new List<Node>(currentPath);
    currentPath.Add (node);
    if (node.Children.Any()) {
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
            PrintPaths (child, currentPath);
    } else {
        //we are at a leaf, print
        foreach (var n in currentPath)
            Console.Write (n.Label);
        Console.WriteLine ();
    }
}
```

Call this on the root node: `PrintPaths (rootnode, null);`

If, instead of printing, you want to return those lists, pass an extra argument, a `List<List<Node>>` to the method, and instead of printing at the end, add the currentpath to the result.

```
var result = new List<List<Node>> ();

GetPaths (rootNode, null, result); //implementation not provided, but trivial
```

Comment: This prints ABDI ABDIE ABDIEF .... it adds leaf to path but still remeber the old path.

Comment: should be fixed. the list isn't shared anymore. I typed this code directly here on S.O. without trying to compile or execute.

Answer (score 0):

Depth First Search using a stack, another clean way of doing it

```
push (root);
while (top ())
{
   pop  (top);
   push (node->right);
   push (node->left);
}
```

this can be done recursively